# Issue deploying latest version of daskhub helm chart in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, dask, dask-kubernetes

I am trying to deploy the latest version of 'daskhub' in a GKE cluster (v1.21.12-gke.1700), but getting the below error with 'traefik'

> helm upgrade --wait --install --dry-run --debug --render-subchart-notes --version 2022.6.0 dhub dask/daskhub --namespace=dhub --values=secrets.yaml --values=config.yaml

```
install.go:190: [debug] WARNING: This chart or one of its subcharts contains CRDs. Rendering may fail or contain inaccuracies.
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "IngressRoute" in version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Middleware" in version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1"]
helm.go:81: [debug] [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "IngressRoute" in version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Middleware" in version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1"]
unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).Run
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/action/install.go:258
main.runInstall
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/install.go:242
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:115
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:850
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:958
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:895
main.main
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/helm.go:80
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
```

https://dask.discourse.group/t/daskhub-helm-chart-fails-with-k8-v1-21-12-gke-1700/943

Comment: **Resolved** : Apparently for 'helm upgrades' the CRDs will not be created . Instead i used  'helm install --debug --render-subchart-notes --version 2022.6.0 dhub1 dask/daskhub --namespace=dhub --values=secrets.yaml --values=config.yaml' this time it worked .

Answer (score 1):

It seems like helm install the resource `IngressRoute` before creating the traefik CRDs, so you can try to install them manually before installing the chart `daskhub`.

You just need to call the command `kubectl apply` on [the manifest files](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.0/user-guides/crd-acme/#ingressroute-definition)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i see that the CRDs are part of chart at https://github.com/dask/dask-gateway/blob/2022.6.1/resources/helm/dask-gateway/crds/traefik.yaml . I did not notice this issue with my previous installs , wondering if there are any recent changes .

Comment: Yes they are part of the chart, but there is no guarantee that the CRDs are installed before the resources which use them, for that I proposed to install them manually.

Comment: I believe helm does not automatically update CRDs at all

Comment: Do we have to always install the CRDs before applying the helm chart ? In this case , what if helm also trying to create the CRD , will it fail with already exists error ?